# One element size container with auto erasing, when data used, pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm looking for patterns or for some ready to use solutions for next problem:

> Container with features:
>
> 1. One element of an arbitrary type storing
> 2. When element is taken from container it gets empty
> 3. When new element is stored, it overwrites previous content
> 4. Thread safety

My naive implementation without thread safety:

```
template<typename T>
class Boxed {
    T* _data;
public:
    Boxed()
        : _data(nullptr)
    {}

    Boxed(const T& data)
        : _data(new T(data))
    {}

    ~Boxed() {
        if(_data != nullptr) {
            delete _data;
        }
    }

    inline
    void setData(const T& data) {
        if(_data != nullptr) {
            delete _data;
        }
        _data = new T(data);
    }

    inline
    T getData() {
        T res(*_data);
        delete _data;
        _data = nullptr;
        return res;
    }

    inline
    bool empty() const {
        return _data == nullptr;
    }

    inline
    operator bool() cons {
        return empty();
    }
};
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: What are you looking for in terms of thread safety?

Comment: Are you reimplementing std::unique_ptr? Also: please read about the rule of 5.

Comment: "Thread safety" is too vague. For an excellent historical example of naive "thread safety" going wrong, look at Java's `Vector` class (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) and avoid the mistake it made.

Comment: @WernerHenze, is it [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))? I'll look at. Thanks a lot for comment!

Comment: @SergeyA, I'm looking for thread safe solution as this container can be used from different threads. I know about mutexes, but thought that it's not need for naive implementation to understand what I waant to get, so I didnt include it in code sample.

Comment: @dFionov Yes, that's the rule. Previously rule of three, now rule of five.

Answer (score 1):

Use a queue of size 2. Protect the underlining array/vector/deque with a mutex. Logic for push and pop is trivial. On push: if not empty then remove old element, insert new one. On pop: It is empty or has size 1, nothing special to do than a regular pop. So it does not overwrite the current one but will replace it. the difference is not observable.

Signatures:

```
class only_one
{
public:
    bool push(T& e);
    bool pop(T& e);
    bool is_empty() const;
}
```

Implementations for thread safe queues with mutex/condition_var can be found in lot of corners of the internet. [Example](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did few implementations with deque/vector/other STL-container, but I'm looking for simpler solution. If it doesn't exist - I will use one of known.